# Developing new SP2010 workflows for SP2013?

Tags: 2013, workflow

I have an interesting scenario where I have to develop a workflow for an SP2013/O365 environment, but it has to be an SP2010 workflow, because Azure is not supported / allowed.  This is a **new** workflow, not a legacy one being migrated to 2013.

How can I go about doing this?  Is it possible to do in VS2012?  Even if I made the first step of the workflow the "Start 2010 WF" action, is that already using the Azure service bus?  Are SP2010 workflow actions available in VS2012?

Would I have to develop a 2010 workflow in VS2010, and then import the workflow into VS2012?  Can this then be deployed as an [integrated workflow app](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/sharepoint-online-integrated-workflow-apps-workflows-as-apps-in-the-hostweb)?  If not, how can I deploy it to the site that needs it?

Am I going to be stuck with doing it all in Designer? (Please tell me no...)

Edit to add: I just want to make it clear that deploying a farm solution is not an option.  This is for SharePoint 2013 online, not on-premises.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seeing as migrated 2010 workflow work, the workflow back-end is all running and functional.

You can still develop 2010 style workflows and deploy them using a normal Farm Solution (as you would in 2010).

You might have trouble in future migrations (as the built-in engine's future isn't clear) and you definitely won't be able to move this workflow to SharePoint online.

The 2010 actions are run by the built-in workflow engine and not the Azure engine.

Use one of the Visual Studio Item Templates below:
[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  I guess I should point out that this is definitely for SharePoint online, deploying a farm solution is not an option.  Considering that, how do you think I can get an SP2010 workflow on to SP2013 online?

Comment: Sadly, in this case, I think only through Designer. Since 2010 workflows use a compiled assembly, you need a farm solution to deploy them (since the user code host service (sandbox) is no longer available online)